# setting javascript parameters?

Tags: php, javascript, html, parameters

So I'm setting the javascript parameters with a PHP script (which works perfectly fine) but the question is how to use those parameters in my javascript? Here's what the function looks like :

```
    function clicked(string cob)
    {
    document.getElementById("watching").innerHTML=cob;
    }
```

and my php(which does the job)

```
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $id=$row['id'];
    $name=$row['name'];
    $url=$row['url'];
    echo "<a href='javascript: clicked($url)'>$name</a> <input type='button' id='delete' value='X' onclick='return Deleteqry($id)' /><br> ";
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `string` so it's just `clicked(cob)`.  Anything else?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: `clicked($url)` should be `clicked(\"$url\")`. This isn't a good way of accomplishing whatever OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

use quotes for $url.

```
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
            $id=$row['id'];
            $name=$row['name'];
            $url=$row['url'];
            echo "<a href='javascript: clicked(\"$url\")'>$name</a> <input type='button' id='delete' value='X' onclick='return Deleteqry($id)' /><br> ";
    }
```

remove type hint for the clicked function

```
    function clicked(cob)
    {
            document.getElementById("watching").innerHTML=cob;
    }
```